# properly pass 2 parameters to a controller laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i have this page that loads a specific record based on the id and this form will allow the user to modify the record here is my code

```
@foreach($modData as $list)
    @endforeach
    <div class="gtdwn">

        <h5>Edit Details</h5>
        <h6>File Information</h6>
        {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'PUT', 'action' => array('sample@savemodfile', $list->subcategoryid, $list->fileid))) }}
            <h6>Filename    : </h6>
            {{ Form::text('eFile', $list->filename ) }}
            <span>File type     : {{ $list->filetype }} </span>
            @if($list->filetype == 'ppt' || $list->filetype == 'pptx')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/pptico.PNG') }}" class="imgico">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'doc' || $list->filetype == 'docx')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/wordico.PNG') }}" class="imgico">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'pdf')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/pdfico.PNG') }}" class="imgico">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'xls' || $list->filetype == 'xlsx')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/excelico.PNG') }}" class="imgico">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'txt')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/txtico.PNG') }}" class="imgico">

            @elseif($list->filetype == 'csv')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/ico/csvico.PNG') }}" class="imgico">
            @endif

            <h6>Size        : {{ $list->filesize }} </h6>
            @if($list->confidential == 'true')
                {{ Form::checkbox('conf', 'true', true , array('id' => 'test5')) }}
                <label for="test5">confidential</label>
            @else
                {{ Form::checkbox('conf', 'true', null , array('id' => 'test5')) }}
                <label for="test5">confidential</label>
            @endif

            {{Form::select('sCategory',[ $list->subcategoryid =>'CURRENT CATEGORY :  ' . $list->subcategoryname . ' | ' . $list->maincategoryname] + $cats )}}

            {{ Form::submit('save', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary defcolor')) }}
        {{ Form::close()}}   

        <br>        
    </div>
```

so far it properly loads the data when the user clicked the submit button it would go to this route

```
Route::put('modifyFile/{sid}/{id}' , array('as' => 'modfyFilesave', 'uses' => 'sample@savemodfile'));
```

i also have supplied the `id` in my form already but when it reaches my controller when i do validation it can't read the data in it

```
public function savemodfile($scid , $id)
{
    $some = Input::get('eFile');
    dd($some);
    $rules = array(
        'eFile' => 'required|min:2|max:250|unique:nsa_fileuploads,filename'
    );

    $messages = array(
        'eFile.required'    => 'Please provide a filename.',
        'eFile.min'         => 'Filename should have atleast 2 characters.',
        'eFile.max'         => 'Filename can only have maximum of 250 characters.',
        'eFile.unique'      => 'Filename already exist.'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules , $messages);
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        dd('some errors');
    }
    else
    {
        dd('okay');
    }
}
```

i tried dumping the value from the `Form::text('eFile',$list->filename)` and i got the value from the view but when i use it inside the validator, even only the required, it always fails. any idea what is wrong with my code? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide a controller method as your action in your from. Does that actually work? Try changing this:

`'action' => array('sample@savemodfile', $list->subcategoryid, $list->fileid)`

To

`'action' => route('modfyFilesave', 
array('sid' => $list->subcategoryid, 'id' => $list->fileid))`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your form with this

```
{{ Form::open(array('files'=>true, 'action' => array('sample@savemodfile', $list->subcategoryid, $list->fileid))) }}
```

in your form  add this line 'files' => true

Hope this code will help you!!

Comment: I don't think he's trying to upload a file. He's posting a file name.